# Why いた is used instead of いる here?

Tags: grammar, manga, modality

Why いた is used instead of いる in the dialogue below?

> なんでえ
>   生{い}きてたのか
>   楓{かえで}ばばあ。

[image]

Comment: I disagree this question is NOT DUPLICATED.  At least not the same problem at [Usage of plain i-adjectives or た form (悪かったｖ悪い、良かったｖいい etc）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21347/usage-of-plain-i-adjectives-or-%e3%81%9f-form-%e6%82%aa%e3%81%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%ef%bd%96%e6%82%aa%e3%81%84-%e8%89%af%e3%81%8b%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%ef%bd%96%e3%81%84%e3%81%84-etc) as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

なんで生きてたのか　ー＞　Why you lived (~after a fight)? (~ How did you survived?)

なんで生きているのかー＞　Why you still living? (~ How come you are still alive?)

Your confusion is caused by this:

てた・ていた　are both the same, the former being a different way to speak it.

（Compare to English wanna＝want to・don't=do not）