# Why is た form used instead of る form here?

Tags: grammar, tense, modality

> するとその横で、耶倶矢がむうとうなる。
>
> 「ふん、本条蒼二が**女だった**とはな……我が目をたばかるとはなかなかやりよる」
>
> 「あ、耶倶矢も**知ってた**のか？」
>
> 士道が問うと、耶倶矢はこくりと首を前に倒してきた。
>
> 「当然だ。颶風の御子は大衆の娯楽にも通じておるわ」

耶倶矢 previously thought 本条蒼二 was male and just realized 本条蒼二 was female. And 士道 said “You know 本条蒼二 too?”

Why are 女だった and 知ってた used instead of 女だ and 知ってる? They are not talking about past things but current status, I suppose?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21347/9831

Comment: Even in English wouldn't you say 'I can't believe she *was* a woman', or 'So she *was* a woman this whole time?'

Comment: 女だった is "modal-ta", but I think this 知ってた is a plain past form. English speakers would also say "Did you know?" in this context, right?

Comment: @naruto Thank you. I see. Sorry I made a small mistake about the context. 耶倶矢 didn’t realize 本条蒼二 was female on her own but was just told the fact by others. So given the context, is the 女だった is still “modal-ta” that expresses discovery?