# What ご苦労なこって means here?

Tags: phrases, manga

I struggle to understand the nuance of ご苦労なこって part in the One Piece panel below.

[image]

なこって is short for なことで right?

I checked the English translation, it reads "No thank you." So, can I understand ご苦労なこって as "I appreciate your offer but... (I refuse)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, こって is a corrupted form of ことで. It's rarely used in reality, and it usually has a scornful overtone in fiction, like in this scene.

This ご苦労なこって may look like an appreciation, but it actually is a sarcasm. It's like "What a (pointless) effort" or "You're working hard for nothing". Zoro is saying Luffy is putting effort to something meaningless.

**EDIT:** Here are other typical examples of こって:

- のんきなこって。
  Ha, [you] are so easygoing (though you shouldn't be).
- 幸せそうなこって。
  [He] seems so happy (though it's not enviable).

This type of こって is interchangeable with こった ([modal-ta](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21347/5010)).

Comment: I see, it's a kind of set phrase. Thanks again!